# Spring data jpa / mysql - how to improve query performance with order by datetime column?

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I am facing an issue with query performance if `order by <datetime column>` is used.

The table contains 6 million rows, the query returns 150K rows, if I don't perform an `order by`, it takes a few seconds to return the data, but if I add `order by <datetime column>` then it takes a few minutes to return the result.  I have `LIMIT 25` to page the result.

My current `sort_buffer_size` is `2MB`, increased to `10MB` did not make any difference (32GB RAM).

I have a composite index which contains the datetime column to be sorted, and if I add `force index` into the query, it returns results in 7 seconds, not bad.  However I am using spring data jpa specification, I don't see a way to force the query to use the index.

So in general, how do I improve the performance of the query if I have `order by <datetime column>`?

Thanks

Comment: A composite index may or may not help -- we need to see the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks!  the problem is resolved, (may not be the best), we optimized the table and the query takes a few seconds now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.  Optimized the tables.  Query now takes a few seconds.